# Magento2 Possible to configure "Decrease Stock When Order is Placed" On storeview level?

Tags: magento2, multistore, manage-stock

I have a Magento 2 installation which has two websites - B2C and B2A. For B2A site I need to disable Stock Management so products won't be subtracted from the inventory when order is placed. I can understand this feature can be made from **Stores->Configuration->Catalog->Inventory->Stock Options**, and set **Decrease Stock When Order is Placed** to **No**. But it seems this option is working only globally, and can't be managed on website / storeview level?

And if this option can not be configured to website level, any suggesstions what else I can do to make Stock management disabled for B2A site?

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, Magento 2 (or 1) does not support website or store view stock level.
So the answer is NO, you cannot do that.
However, there is [this official project](https://github.com/magento-engcom/msi) that should be released sometime this year in a stable version that will allow you do to what you need and even more